# How to check if no beacons are available Android

Tags: android, beacon, estimote

I am trying to play around with Beacons and I have got this code: 
By following [this](http://developer.estimote.com/ibeacon/tutorial/part-1-setting-up/) tutorial:

**Activity2.java**

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    //String myString = MyViewClass.infoToPass;

    public static final String TAG = "Airport";
    TextView tvFooter;

    private static final Map<String, List<String>> PLACES_BY_BEACONS;

    // TODO: replace "<major>:<minor>" strings to match your own beacons.
    static {
        Map<String, List<String>> placesByBeacons = new HashMap<>();
        placesByBeacons.put("22504:48827", new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("Heavenly Sandwiches");
            // read as: "Heavenly Sandwiches" is closest
            // to the beacon with major 22504 and minor 48827
            add("Green & Green Salads");
            // "Green & Green Salads" is the next closest
            add("Mini Panini");
            // "Mini Panini" is the furthest away
        }});
        placesByBeacons.put("648:12", new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("Mini Panini");
            add("Green & Green Salads");
            add("Heavenly Sandwiches");
        }});
        PLACES_BY_BEACONS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(placesByBeacons);
    }

    private List<String> placesNearBeacon(Beacon beacon) {
        String beaconKey = String.format("%d:%d", beacon.getMajor(), beacon.getMinor());
        if (PLACES_BY_BEACONS.containsKey(beaconKey)) {
            return PLACES_BY_BEACONS.get(beaconKey);
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    private Region region;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        //updateCordinate("Just some random text");

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
        beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> list) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onBeaconsDiscovered");
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    Beacon nearestBeacon = list.get(0);
                    List<String> places = placesNearBeacon(nearestBeacon);
                    // TODO: update the UI here
                    Log.d(TAG, "Nearest places: " + places);
                }
                else{
                    // this line is not executing
                    Log.d(TAG, "You are not in area of beacons");
                }
            }
        });
        region = new Region("ranged region", UUID.fromString("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"), null, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
        SystemRequirementsChecker.checkWithDefaultDialogs(this);

        beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onServiceReady");
                beaconManager.startRanging(region);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        beaconManager.stopRanging(region);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
        super.onPause();
    }


    //public void updateCordinate(String text1) {
     //   tvFooter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFooter);
     //   tvFooter.setText("Location is :" + myString);
   // }
}
```

Now what I want it:

- If I don't have any Beacons around me, I want to check for it and store that value in some variable so that I can use it in other class *(non-activity  class)*.
- Also how do I check for range from it? *(I know it's beyond the scope of this question but little idea will be welcomed)*

Comment: isn't your class should be an extension of Service. U need service for beacon.  eg.   public class EstimoteService extends Service implements BeaconManager.RangingListener, BeaconManager.MonitoringListener, then in your activity call this  startService(new Intent(this, EstimoteService.class));  of course you need to ensure your bluetooth is turn on and has permission.

Comment: Hello Thank You for your comments. Well I have other class: `MyApplication.java`. I download GitHub project from [Here](https://github.com/wondek/estimote-android-tutorial-ea99e83c)

Answer (score 0):

//you may ignore the notification code, for my usage of Beacons in my app, i 
//to send notification to my app even through the app is not open when a beacon //is in/out range.

```
 public class EstimoteService extends Service implements BeaconManager.RangingListener, BeaconManager.MonitoringListener {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 123;
    private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION = new Region("regionId", null, null, null);
    private Beacon beaconFound;

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        initResources();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);

        // Default values are 5s of scanning and 25s of waiting time to save CPU cycles.
        // In order for this demo to be more responsive and immediate we lower down those values.
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1), 0);
        beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady() {
                try {
                    beaconManager.startRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void initResources() {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
        beaconManager.setRangingListener(this);
        beaconManager.setMonitoringListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
        if (beaconFound == null) {
            // Get the first available beaconFound
            if (beacons.isEmpty())
                return;

            beaconFound = beacons.get(0);
            final Region beaconRegion = new Region("regionId", beaconFound.getProximityUUID(), beaconFound.getMajor(), beaconFound.getMinor());
            beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onServiceReady() {
                    try {
                        beaconManager.startMonitoring(beaconRegion);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnteredRegion(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
        postNotification("Entered region");
        System.out.println("---> enter region");
    }

    @Override
    public void onExitedRegion(Region region) {
        postNotification("Exited region");
        System.out.println("---> exit region");
    }

    private void postNotification(String msg) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.beacon_gray).setContentTitle("XXX").setContentText(msg);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @kggoh Thank You for your valuable answer. I am just having problem in `beaconFound ` and `imports` Well I will love if you please post complete code. Your code looks so amazing, but I am having hard time integrating with my code. Thank You.

Comment: as requested. here it is.

Comment: Hello @kggoh Thank You very much for your answer and special edit for me. Well as I studied so much codes and now I am confused. The above class `class EstimoteService` is without errors. But I am now confused how to access it. I include it in my project and it's not showing me any errors. Can you please show me how to make it work. :(

Comment: you need a service in android manifest...  <!-- Estimote -->
        <service
            android:name=".Service.UtuEstimoteService"
            android:exported="false" />      . Do go read how to use a service in android. BTW, the code works with real physical beacon.